# Extract data from html/xml

Tags: html, xml, xpath, webharvest

I'm using Webharvest to retrieve data from websites. It converts the html pages to xml documents before getting for me the wanted data based on the xPath provided.

Now I'm working on a page like this: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sDP9yuhR) Where I showed the blocks I'd like to get. Each block should be returned as a single unit.

the xPath the first element of the block is: `//div[@id="layer22"]/b/span[@style="background-color: #FFFF99"]`
I tested it and it gives all "bloc start" elements.

the xPath of the last element of the block is: `//div[@id="layer22"]/a[contains(.,"Join")]`
I tested it and it gives all the "bloc end" elements.

The  xPath should return a set of blocks as:

`(xPath)[1]` = block 1

`(xPath)[2]` = block 2

....

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just to be sure; You want an XPath query which takes as argument the ID a block of HTML, and this returns the 2 specified elements from this block? What is your main task? Do you want to retrieve all specified elements from a page in pairs?

Comment: I want a path that returns all blocks (a block is delimited by Start & End block)
Therefore, block N can be got using `(xPath)[N]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use** (for the first wanted result):

```
  ($first)[1] | ($last)[1]

|

  ($first)[1]/following::node()
       [count(.|($last)[1]/preceding::node()) = count(($last)[1]/preceding::node())]
```

where you need to substitute `$first` with:

```
//div[@id="layer22"]/b/span[@style="background-color: #FFFF99"]
```

and substitute `$last` with:

```
//div[@id="layer22"]/a[contains(.,"Join")]
```

To get the k-th result, substitute in the final expression `($first)[1]` with `($first)[{k}]` and `($last)[1]` with `($last)[{k}]`, where `{k}` should be replaced by the *number* k.

**This technique follows directly from the well-known** *Kayessian formula for set intersection in XPath 1.0*:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

which selects the intersection of the two node-sets `$ns1` and `$ns2` .

Here is XSLT verification with a simple example:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="v1" select=
  "(//num[. = 3])[1]/following-sibling::*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="v2" select=
  "(//num[. = 7])[1]/preceding-sibling::*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "$v1[count(.|$v2) = count($v2)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**applies the XPath expression and the selected nodes are copied to the output:**

```
<num>04</num>
<num>05</num>
<num>06</num>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But when trying `($first)[1]/following::node()[count(.|($last)[1]) = count(($last)[1])]` after substitution, I only get `<a href='../?INDIVIDUALS_ID=1642'>Join</a>` wich is $last of the first block !

Comment: Well, when using `($first)[1]/following::node()[count(.|($last)[1]/preceding-sibling::*) = count(($last)[1]/preceding-sibling::*)]` it gives me some acceptable result containing only text between tags `<tag>text</tag>`. How can I get everything within the block (text in/out tags) ?

Comment: @Batis610: You have some mistakes in constructing the expression -- for your convenience I have updated the answer and have provided a complete example.

Comment: @Batis610: You should *only* use `following::` and `preceding::` -- not any sibling axes.

Comment: @Batis610: I also fixed the expression -- try it now.

Comment: thanks It works now.
However, I want to store all block in a variable $blocks that I use later to get specific blocks `$block[N]`. Is there anyway to do that with xPath ?

Comment: Sure, just specify all the expressions (one for each block) united with the XPath union operator `|`. If you have an XPath 2.0 implementation, this can be conveniently written as a sequence: `for $k in 1 to count(exprForStartOfBlocks) return exprForTheKthBlock`

Comment: That's great. But still one little problem: `$first` and `$last` aren't in the result, how can I include them?

Comment: @Batis610: This isn't true, or you have modified the expression. This expression explicitly contains `($first)[$k]` and `($last)[$k]` so they *are* selected.